# Python exception handling within module

Tags: python, exception, module, gammu

Stackoverflow posts helped me a lot with Python, however I stuck on this one. I cannot figure out how to simply skip module if it has exceptions within it. Also, if it happens I like to alter one variable so rest of code would know to skip functionality related with that module.

I have main.py which is loading my module sms.py. Here you also see my attempt which does not work:

```
try:
    import sms
except ImportError:
    print "Ok, lets skip that module"
    dont_use_sms = 1
```

Part of sms.py which causes exception looks following:

```
import gammu

sm = gammu.StateMachine()

sm.ReadConfig()
try:
    sm.Init()   # this one to be exact
except:
    raise
```

when I run this I get following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 10, in <module>
    import sms
  File "/path/to/sms.py", line 7, in <module>
    sm.Init()
gammu.ERR_DEVICENOTEXIST: {'Text': u"Error opening device, it doesn't exist.", 'Code': 4, 'Where': 'Init'}
```

I have tried to alter exception by putting gammu.ERR_DEVICENOTEXIST as argument, however it didn't help.
I feel that that exception should be somehow handled by sms.py and properly forwarded to main.py, but cannot figure out how.

By the way, I know what causes gammu.ERR_DEVICENOTEXIST and that is not a problem. Question is about how to continue with rest of program if it appears.

That you for suggestions.

Comment: I don't see why you have bare code in `sms.py`... You should wrap that in a `init_sms` function or similar... Then from `main.py` just use `import sms` and use a try/except around `sms.init_sms()` where suitable in the main logic - that way, you can detect device not connected in main, do whatever, and retry `sms.init_sms()` or otherwise follow another branch of logic

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your main.py.

Instead of:

```
except ImportError:
```

you can say:

```
except:
```

And then it should continue.

PS: Naked except statements are not good style

Comment: This one actually works and does what I wanted. But I will be looking forward, because. as mentioned, it is not good practice. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. But you already have a naked except clause in sms.py. So you have precedent.